# Flip axis in funnel plot in R

Tags: r

I would like to flip the Y axis in funnel plot in `metafor library`. I would like to have y axis in descending order. This is how it looks now:

[image]
I tried both

```
library("metafor")

funnel(x = prumer$AVGT, sei = prumer$invSE , xlab = "Observed effect", ylab = "1/SE", xlim=c(-3,3), ylim=c(2500,0))

funnel(x = prumer$AVGT, sei = prumer$invSE , xlab = "Observed effect", ylab = "1/SE", xlim=c(-3,3), ylim=c(0,2500))
```

but it did not help. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Perhaps pass  `sei = rev(prumer$invSE)` to `funnel`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik unfortunately no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument `sei` is for passing the standard errors to the `funnel()` function. `invSE` suggests that you are passing the *inverse* standard errors to this argument. This is not appropriate and leads to the funnel plot looking really messed up. If you want to put the inverse standard errors on the y-axis, pass the standard errors to `sei` and set `yaxis="seinv"`. See the documentation of the `forest()` function here:

https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/funnel.html

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I suspect your motivation for trying to flip the y-axis might actually be related to the way the plot looks, but it only looks this way because of the way you are using the function.